# Introduction to recurrent neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, neural-networks

I have two questions:

1- What are the applications of recurrent neural networks?

2- Can you recommend some good resources/papers/tutorials that introduce recurrent neural networks?

Answer (score 5):

The major applications of Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) is sequence modelling. Applications like Machine Translation, Named Entity Recognition, Part-of-Speech Tagging etc.(since, i work in NLP, all the examples are from NLP)

Some of the resources which I found helpful for a beginner are:

- Supervised Sequence Labelling with Recurrent Neural Networks By Alex Graves's Thesis
- [Bengio's Deep Learning Draft Chapter](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~bengioy/dlbook/rnn.html)
- Also, the RNN tutorial link containing Python Code,http://www.nehalemlabs.net/prototype/blog/2013/10/10/implementing-a-recurrent-neural-network-in-python/

Specifically the part on Backpropagation Through Time was well explained in the thesis.

Comment: Dude thank you. But can you please also explain how RNN compares or relates to density estimation methods? Or whatever statistical primitives?